# How to work documentlistener with jtabbedpane?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane, documentlistener

Open Two files By using Jtabbedpane.Document listener work each file independently.If you modify one file document listener enabled only for particular file. How to do this?. When open two files

Here is my code,

```
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameAdapter;
import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class Close extends javax.swing.JFrame {
JTextArea tx;

File file;
String filename=null;
int i=0;
boolean update =false;
public Close() {
initComponents();
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

tp = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
Open = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

jMenu1.setText("File");

Open.setText("Open");
Open.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        OpenActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});
jMenu1.add(Open);

jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
layout.setHorizontalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
);
layout.setVerticalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
);

pack();
 }// </editor-fold>                        

 private void OpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

final JFileChooser jc = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal=  jc.showOpenDialog(Close.this);
String title;
String s=null;
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)     
file = jc.getSelectedFile();
if (jc.getSelectedFile()!= null) {
   BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("");
    StringBuffer str1 = new StringBuffer("");
    StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder("");
    StringBuilder sbHex = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sbText = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sbResult = new StringBuilder();
    final StringBuilder pb = new StringBuilder();
    int bytesCounter =0;        
    String helloWorldInHex=null;
    int value=0;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        try {

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    String t = str.toString();
   filename=file.getPath();
   final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("",true,true); 
  final String filePath=file.getAbsolutePath();
  i++;
  internalFrame.setName("Doc "+i);
   tx=new JTextArea();
     internalFrame.setTitle(filename);
    try {
        internalFrame.setSelected(true);
    } 
    catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }           
    tp.add(internalFrame);
    try{
        tp.setSelectedIndex(i-1);  
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ioe){   
    }
    tx.setText(t);
    internalFrame.add(tx);
  internalFrame.setVisible(true);

  Document doc=tx.getDocument();
  doc.addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
       @Override
       public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        update =true;
       }

       @Override
       public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
           update =true;
       }

       @Override
       public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
           update =true;
       }
   });
    internalFrame.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {


            String name=tx.getName();

 if(update==true){

      update=false;
    int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                                      "Save Changes to this Document", "Quit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
        int chooserStatus;
    if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
      boolean success;
            String editorString;
            FileWriter fwriter;
            PrintWriter outputFile;
            try {
                DataOutputStream d = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
                String line = tx.getText();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(line));
                while((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
                    d.writeBytes(line + "\r\n");
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ee) {       
                success = false;
            }
     success = true;
            i--;
           tp.remove(internalFrame);
       }
    else if(reply==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
    {
        i--;
  tp.remove(internalFrame);
   }
  }
 else 
 {
      i--;
tp.remove(internalFrame);
 }

        }
    });   

   }

   }                                    
  public static void main(String args[]) {

java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
           try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                       UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        new Open().setVisible(true);
    }
});
 }
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenuItem Open;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
 private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tp;
// End of variables declaration                   
  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Wow, this is like the 10th time this question has been asked. The contents of each tabbed should a self contained unit of work, with no knowledge of any other tabs or their contents.  To this, you should create a separate "editor" class, which contains the a reference to the file, the view (the text editor) and a `DocumentListener`), it should provide functionality to allow external classes to query it about the state of the content (changed or not) and maybe even provide `ChangeListener` support...

Comment: i am new to swing. Can You provide any related example or link.@MadProgrammer

Comment: [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: i need example related documentlistener with jtabbedpane. @MadProgrammer

Comment: You should write the code yourself.

Comment: They're not, related, that's the point (and probably your problem)...everything you need to get started is within that tutorial. Create a single "editor" get that working and then figure out how to add them to the tabs...

Comment: Can i add my code please give me suggestion. problem is modify the file1 but documentlistener enabled for file2 not for file1. @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class Open extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  JTextArea tx;
  ArrayList<String> fileList;
  File file;
  Map<Integer,String> m;
  Map<String,Boolean> m1;
  String filename=null;
   int i=0;
  int j=-1;
  boolean update =false;
  boolean changed=false;
public Open() {

   fileList=new ArrayList<String>();
   m=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
      m1=new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
initComponents();
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    tp = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    Open = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jMenu1.setText("File");

    Open.setText("Open");
    Open.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            OpenActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(Open);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void OpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

    final JFileChooser jc = new JFileChooser();
   int returnVal=  jc.showOpenDialog(Open.this);
    String title;
    String s=null;
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)     
    file = jc.getSelectedFile();
      if (jc.getSelectedFile()!= null) {
       BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("");
        StringBuffer str1 = new StringBuffer("");
        StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder("");
        StringBuilder sbHex = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbText = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbResult = new StringBuilder();
        final StringBuilder pb = new StringBuilder();
        int bytesCounter =0;        
        String helloWorldInHex=null;
        int value=0;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            try {

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        String t = str.toString();
       filename=file.getPath();
       final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("",true,true); 
      final String filePath=file.getAbsolutePath();
      i++;
      internalFrame.setName("Doc "+i);
       tx=new JTextArea();
         internalFrame.setTitle(filename);
        try {
            internalFrame.setSelected(true);
        } 
        catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }           
        tp.add(internalFrame);
        try{
            tp.setSelectedIndex(i-1);  
        }
        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ioe){   
        }
        tx.setText(t);
        internalFrame.add(tx);
      internalFrame.setVisible(true);
     final Document doc=tx.getDocument();

           doc.addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
           @Override
           public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
               System.out.println("insert");


             Component c = tp.getSelectedComponent();
        if( c instanceof JInternalFrame)
        {
            JInternalFrame f = (JInternalFrame)c;
            if(!fileList.contains(f.getTitle()))
            {


                fileList.add(f.getTitle());
                 update =true;
            }
        }

           }

           @Override
           public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
               update =true;
           }

           @Override
           public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
               update =true;
           }
       });    

        internalFrame.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {


                String name=tx.getName();

              Component c = tp.getSelectedComponent();
        if( c instanceof JInternalFrame)
        {
             JInternalFrame f = (JInternalFrame)c;

        String path=f.getTitle();


         if(fileList.contains(path)){
             fileList.remove(path);


          update=false;
        int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                                          "Save Changes to this Document", "Quit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
           int chooserStatus;
        if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
          boolean success;
                String editorString;
                FileWriter fwriter;
                PrintWriter outputFile;
                try {
                     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                    DataOutputStream d = new DataOutputStream(fos);
                    System.out.println("conetent2            "+filename);

                    String line = tx.getText();
                   System.out.println("conetent            "+line);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(line));
                    while((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
                        d.writeBytes(line + "\r\n");
                    }

                }
                catch (IOException ee) {     
                     System.out.println("conetent     qqw112222       ");
                    success = false;
                }

         success = true;
                i--;
               tp.remove(internalFrame);
           }
        else if(reply==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
        {
            i--;
      tp.remove(internalFrame);
       }
      }

     else 
     {

          i--;
    tp.remove(internalFrame);
     }
        }     
           }
        });   


    j++;



   }

  }                                    
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
               try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                           UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            new Open().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenuItem Open;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tp;
// End of variables declaration                   
 }
```