# Open two files by using Jtabbedpane but file2 text override to file1 in swing?

Tags: java, swing

Load the two files into textarea by using jtabbedpane.Modify text two files then Close Jinternalframe it shows Joptionpane dialog box, If yes modify text saved that particular file but my problem file2 text override into the file1. how to overcome this problem?

Here is my code,

```
 import java.awt.Component;
  import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.DataOutputStream;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import java.io.StringReader;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;
 import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
 import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 import javax.swing.JTextArea;
 import javax.swing.UIManager;
 import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
 import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
 import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
 import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameAdapter;
 import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent;
public class Open extends javax.swing.JFrame {
JTextArea tx;
ArrayList<String> fileList;
File file;

String filename=null;
int i=0;

 boolean update =false;
public Open() {

   fileList=new ArrayList<String>();

initComponents();
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    tp = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    Open = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jMenu1.setText("File");

    Open.setText("Open");
    Open.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            OpenActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(Open);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void OpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

    final JFileChooser jc = new JFileChooser();
    int returnVal=  jc.showOpenDialog(Open.this);
    String title;
    String s=null;
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)     
    file = jc.getSelectedFile();

    if (jc.getSelectedFile()!= null) {
       BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("");
        StringBuffer str1 = new StringBuffer("");
        StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder("");
        StringBuilder sbHex = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbText = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbResult = new StringBuilder();
        final StringBuilder pb = new StringBuilder();
        int bytesCounter =0;        
        String helloWorldInHex=null;
        int value=0;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            try {

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        String t = str.toString();
       filename=file.getPath();
       final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("",true,true); 
      final String filePath=file.getAbsolutePath();
      i++;
      internalFrame.setName("Doc "+i);
       tx=new JTextArea();
         internalFrame.setTitle(filename);
        try {
            internalFrame.setSelected(true);
        } 
        catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }           
        tp.add(internalFrame);
        try{
            tp.setSelectedIndex(i-1);  
        }
        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ioe){   
        }
        tx.setText(t);
        internalFrame.add(tx);
      internalFrame.setVisible(true);
      final Document doc=tx.getDocument();

           doc.addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
           @Override
           public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
               System.out.println("insert");


             Component c = tp.getSelectedComponent();
        if( c instanceof JInternalFrame)
        {
            JInternalFrame f = (JInternalFrame)c;
            if(!fileList.contains(f.getTitle()))
            {
                fileList.add(f.getTitle());
                 update =true;
            }
        }
           }

           @Override
           public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
               update =true;
           }

           @Override
           public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
               update =true;
           }
       });    

        internalFrame.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
            String name=tx.getName();
      Component c = tp.getSelectedComponent();
        if( c instanceof JInternalFrame)
        {
             JInternalFrame f = (JInternalFrame)c;
      String path=f.getTitle();
   if(fileList.contains(path)){
             fileList.remove(path);

          update=false;
        int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                                          "Save Changes to this Document", "Quit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
           int chooserStatus;
        if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
          boolean success;
                String editorString;
                FileWriter fwriter;
                PrintWriter outputFile;
                try {

            DataOutputStream d = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(jc.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
            String line = tx.getText();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(line));
            while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                d.writeBytes(line + "\r\n");
            }


                }
                catch (IOException ee) {     

                    success = false;
                }

         success = true;
                i--;
               tp.remove(internalFrame);
           }
        else if(reply==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
        {
            i--;
      tp.remove(internalFrame);
       }
      }

     else 
     {
         System.out.println("fgjqq111133");
          i--;
    tp.remove(internalFrame);
     }
        }     
           }
        });   

    }

    }                                    
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
               try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                           UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            new Open().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenuItem Open;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tp;
// End of variables declaration                   
 }
```

Comment: Looks like a recently popular [homework assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bjava%5d%20%5bswing%5d%20jtabbedpane%20file). Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that focuses on the particular problem you are having.

Comment: Shouldn't `DataOutputStream d = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(jc.getSelectedFile().getPath()));` be something like `DataOutputStream d = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(path)));`? +1 to @trashgod suggestion of an MCVE.

Comment: this is my complete code @trashgod

Comment: *"this is my complete code"*  Is it Minimal?

Comment: Have you reviewed the examples? What are `file1` and `file2`?

Comment: Don't dump all the code into a single class. Separate the individual "elements" into there own classes and manage the individual responsibilities. Start by getting a single editor work in isolation and then start bundling it together

Comment: i am open any two files through open menuitem form my system @trashgod

Comment: Thank u for reply.i modify code based on ur suggestions but same problem. @AndrewThompson

Comment: thank you for suggestion.how overcome this problem can you give the suggestion@MadProgrammer

Comment: I'd follow @MadProgrammer's suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646163/how-to-work-documentlistener-with-jtabbedpane?s=4|0.0000#comment41897788_26646163).

Comment: right now code is working. can you identify my problem? @trashgod

Comment: provided link is working for recently opened file only @trashgod

Comment: i didnt get what ur asking? @AndrewThompson

Comment: Each tab's content should manage it one file.

Comment: i didnt get?@trashgod